# The problem with classification in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Random forest classification gives the following results with empty pixels.

[image]
https://code.earthengine.google.com/aa1956fb4f88f402dcf570bfd37b0a2c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Landsat median image you are using to do the classification has some bands that contain masked values (e.g., `'SR_CLOUD_QA'`). Thus, an easy workaround is to select only the bands you are interested in using for the classification and that do not contain masked values. In this case, I assume these bands are `'SR_1 - SR_5`, `'SR_B7'` and `'ST_B6'`.

```
var landsat_median =landsat5.median()
                            .clip(bostanliq)
                            .select(['SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3',
                            'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B7', 'ST_B6']);
```

[image: image without masked pixels]